# Creating temporary sketches for editing in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, editing

I administer an enterprise geodatabase consisting of building and parcel data. It's crucial that no schema changes are made and that no additional feature classes are added to the database as that might interfere with regularly patching of the databases.

The users says they're often in need for guidelines to facilitate construction, editing or staking and find themselves annoyed by the constant switching of edit sessions to an temporarily database as they're generally more used to work with cad based software.

It is not suitable to use existing lines or points in the database as guidelines and simply delete them as multiple attributes need to be filled in and also there are some topology rules preventing certain geometries.

I thus wonder if there is any way to construct temporary sketches or to create graphic with the existing construction tools like tracing or to create some kind of versioned and editable database view in the database to prevent the user from switching database. I know there are some addin for guidelines but it is unsupported and far to unstable to use.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, do the temporary sketches need to be viewed globally by many users?

Comment: No i don't think that should be necessary. These sketches are only to be used in a specific edit session.